# Reverse the order of file matching as arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, ls

I have a program that reads files in a certain order. For this example, they all have the same extension, txt

```
{program_name} {input 1...} {output}
```

I happen to name the output file name "a.txt" so it comes as the first result when I invoke `ls`, which shows the order of files being fed to this command:

```
{program_name} *.txt
```

I would like the first result to show up as the last one. How can I reverse the order of the star matching? If I need to use pipe, what's the syntax for feeding in arguments properly so that any special character or white-space will be quoted properly?

Comment: do you need a full reverse, or just have the first argument passed as the last? In the latter case, this will do `wrapper(){ f=$1; shift; your_program "$@" "$f"; }`

Comment: @mosvy Yes, the latter. This works for me. Thank you. I am still hoping for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making use of `zsh`:

```
zsh -c 'program *.txt(.^on)'
```

The `(.^on)` is a `zsh` modifier for the `*.txt` pattern that makes it match only regular files (the `.`) and that will order (`o`) the resulting list in reverse (`^`) lexicographical order (`n`).

This would start a non-interactive `zsh` shell that would run `program` with the generated list of filenames as command line arguments.  The command would properly handle reversing the list of arguments, even if they contained spaces or newlines etc. in the filenames.

Example:

```
$ touch {a..d}.txt
$ echo *.txt
a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
```

```
$ zsh -c 'echo *.txt(.^on)'
d.txt c.txt b.txt a.txt
```

---

A non-`zsh` solution:

```
set --
for fname in *.txt; do
    set -- "$fname" "$@"
done

program "$@"
```

or, using a named array in e.g. `bash`,

```
args=()
for fname in *.txt; do
    args=( "$fname" "${args[@]}" )
done

program "${args[@]}"
```

In both of these code snippets, an array is built up from the names matching the `*.txt` pattern.  Each name is pushed onto the array at the front, so the effect is that the array ends up having the last name first.

In the first instance, we use the list of positional parameters as the array.  That code should work in any `sh`-like shell.

---

If you just need the first name last in the list of arguments to your program, and can let the other names be in the order they are expanded in, then the following would do that (in any `sh`-like shell):

```
set -- *.txt
fname=$1
shift
program "$@" "$fname"
```

Alternatively, using `bash`-specific syntax and a named array,

```
args=( *.txt )
program "${args[@]:1}" "${args[0]}"
```

`"${args[@]:1}"` would expand to all elements of the `args` array (individually quoted) from element `1` onwards.

Testing again with `echo`:

```
$ args=( *.txt )
$ echo "${args[@]:1}" "${args[0]}"
b.txt c.txt d.txt a.txt
```

Comment: For your first example, I get: `a.txt b.txt d.txt c.txt` even after I run zsh without .zshrc file using: `zsh -d -f`

Comment: @Forethinker Now fixed. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Awesome. Go zsh!